# Bob's head transcends item pools?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I've run into bob's head 3 times in a single run. I picked it up every time and even used it in an attempt to remove it from the pool. Why does it keep popping up even though I've picked it up? These 3 occurrences happened all on different levels.

Answer (score 5):

Bob's Rotten Head appears in two item pools- the Item Room pool and the Gold Chest Pool. Removing it from one pool doesn't remove it from the other so it is possible, if you're unlucky, to get it twice in a run- once from each.

As well as this, Bob's Rotten Head can drop from Sloth/Mega Sloth. This is independent from item pools, so you can get it a third time this way.